# why animation doesn't work lottie react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a problem.
I'm using lottie for a react native app, but the animation doesn't work, only I can see the image, but not the animation.
Someone can help me ?

resources:
https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native
code

```
<>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{player: ''}}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          player: Yup.string()
            .min(3, 'Musth be more 3 letters')
            .max(15, 'must be less than 15 letters')
            .required('Sorry, this field is required'),
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, {resetForm}) => {
          
        }}>
        {({
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <>
           .....
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>

      <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={false} visible={visible}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            alignContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <LottieView
            source={require('../assets/loading.json')}
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}
            autoPlay
            loop
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </>
```

Answer (score 1):

const Index: React.FC = () => {
const lottieViewRef = useRef(null)

```
return (
    <View style={stylesWithTheme.loadingContainer}>
        <LottieView
            ref={lottieViewRef}
            onLayout={() => lottieViewRef.current?.play()}
            speed={1}
            autoPlay

            loop
            source={loadding} />
    </View>
)
```

}